# PHP copy vs file_put_contents

Tags: php, copy, file-put-contents

I got access to both a path and content, both as strings.

I want to copy the content from one place to another. I can use `copy` or `file_put_contents`. They are different functions but in my case they will result in the same thing.

Are there any advantages with using one over the other? Is some of the faster, more reliable etc?

#### Path

```
/some/path/to/file.txt
```

#### Content

```
Some content
```

#### References

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: @Uchiha But when the file is already on disk and in memory either will work provided you give the right parameters.

Comment: You can find both implementations in http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_MASTER/ext/standard/file.c. Both use the stream API underneath. You can use https://pecl.php.net/package/vld to get the OPCodes for both calls to see if it's a huge difference between the two. Use Xdebug to profile it. If you cannot be bothered with that, the difference is likely not important enough.

Comment: @Uchiha That was why I wrote "They are different functions but in my case they will result in the same thing." ;) I want to know the advantages or disadvantages because I have the option to use one of them.

Comment: just use one and be done with it. in your regular webdev scenario, there won't be a relevant difference. you are basically asking us to point out edge cases.

Comment: @Gordon Which one would you use? I saw that copy has support for PHP4. One small advantage, but most people use PHP5+ so that does not matter that much.

Comment: Right. Because PHP4 is dead. Unless I had to deal with ancient legacy code, I wouldn't base my decision for or against a function on that detail. I don't have a strong preference on which to use here. Since you say you have that file's content in memory already, I'd probably use `file_put_contents`.

Comment: @Gordon I choose to use copy after all. The reason is it returns true on success and that fit my function better. file_put_contents returns bytes. It was a question about details but I did not know that before I got the answers. Thanks!

Comment: and `file_put_contents` returns false on failure. not much of a difference if that's the only detail you are interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, return values of `copy()` are less ambigous.

Both of them are using the same stream copy function, but in order to use `file_put_contents()` to copy files, the data must be read to memory beforhand.

So it is very likely that the latter is slower than `copy()`, at least in mass copy.

Also be advised that `file_put_contents()` can return values which could be interpreted as `FALSE`, even if it succeeded (for example, it will return 0 if you just use it to create an empty file.)
So always use the *"identical"* comparison operator (`===`) to check the result of the function.

Comment: how exactly is http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_MASTER/ext/standard/file.c#1657 *simply using the OS' copy mechanism*?

Comment: Good point, It looks like it's actually using some kind of custom STDIO function. I'll edit my answer, thanks dude!

Comment: file_get_contents and copy both use PHP's streaming API underneath as far as I can see

Comment: yeah, it can be traced back to line 1116 (streams.c) stream->ops->write(stream, buf, towrite); It must be some kind of wrapper for the regular C stream write function. Unfortunately I'm not in C, so it's mostly gibberish to me.